# What to do with ''attempted relative import with no known parent package'' in VS?

Tags: python, django

it is PS C:\storefront> & C:/Users/ANJALY/.virtualenvs/storefront-qOrq4PPp/Scripts/python.exe c:/storefront/playground/urls.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\storefront\playground\urls.py", line 3, in      from . import views ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package PS C:\storefront>.

i tried to change it to subpackage.

Comment: use `manage.py` and set the `PYTHON_PATH` at the same directory.

Comment: Relative imports are primarily for *modules*, and you appear to be trying to execute such a module as a script. There are ways to "fix" a script to allow relative imports, but I would recommend trying to distinguish between modules and scripts first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.